# How to set percentage width for a nested element not of direct parent but of parent's parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css, nested

I have three divs inside each other. I want the innermost div's width to be set in percent with respect to the div of the outermost div. This forms part of a row that has to be appended dynammiclly.

```
trHTML += '<td id="'+tnum+'">
              <div style="height: 20px;">//outermost div 100px width
                <div id="d'+divid +'" style="height: 20px;float:left;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color: ' + color + '; font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial Black; width:'+ util +'%;">
                  ' + weekno.TotalUtilization +
                  '<div style="float:right; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(102,197,232);width:'+ sfin +'%;">
                   </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
           </td>';
```

The width of second width is decided on the variable **"util"** in percentage, wrt to its parent. Width of innermost div is also decide dynamically by the variable **"sfin"**.I want the width of the innermost div to be also decided on the basis of the outermost div, not the second div as it happens.

> **Example:** If outermostdiv width 100px; and util =50; then width of second div is 50px. and if sfin =50; then width of innermost div
>   becomes 50% of 50px = 25px;I want sfin to be equal to 50% of 100=
>   50px.

What can be the ways to do this in Jquery and **also to place the divs side by side**? I'm new to coding so all the help is appreciated.

Comment: Store the width of the parent div in a variable, use calculations to divide the width by 2 and use the .css() method to add a width to the child element, equalling to newly calculated value

Comment: Its not always 50%, **depends on variable util and sfin.** @EthanBristow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done with CSS, where you set `position: relative` to the outermost `div` and `position: absolute` to the innermost.

Doing like that the innermost relates its position and size to the outermost

Updated

To position the innermost next to the middle `div`, use this for its left position: `left:'+ util +'%;`

```html
<div>"sfin" is 50%</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="tnum">
      <div style="height: 20px; width: 100px; position: relative;">
        <div id="did" style="height: 20px;float:left;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color: red; font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial Black; width:50%;overflow: hidden;">
          weekno.TotalUtilization
          <div style="position: absolute; top:0; left: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(102,197,232);width:50%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>"sfin" is 25%</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="tnum">
      <div style="height: 20px; width: 100px; position: relative;">
        <div id="did" style="height: 20px;float:left;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-color: red; font-weight: bold;font-family: Arial Black; width:50%;overflow: hidden;">
          weekno.TotalUtilization
          <div style="position: absolute; top:0; left: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(102,197,232);width:25%;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any way to eliminate the white space in between? @LGSon

Comment: @AyushiZile Updated my answer with a suggestion

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted! Thanks so much :) @LGSon